# python 3 ftp dir into a list

Tags: python, ftp

the ftp site I am accessing doesn't support MLSD. I can use nlst to get a list of files, but nlst() simply returns the name of the files instead of details that dir() displays

```
ftpObj.dir()

drwxr-xr-x   2 ada      storage         0 Nov 12 00:38 Deltas
drwxr-xr-x   2 ada      storage         0 Nov 10 22:38 History
```

so, I tried a roundabout way (as recommended in another post):

```
data=[]
print(data.__len__())
data.append(ftpObj.dir())
print(data.__len__())
```

the output of the first print above is 0 and the output of the second print is 1. however, I am unable to access the information within data, i.e. if I try

```
for line in data:
    print(line)
```

the output is

```
None
```

how can I see what is inside - data - above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass data.append as last argument to `FTP.dir()`,

```
print(data.__len__())
ftpObj.dir(data.append)
print(data.__len__())
```

**FTP.dir(argument[, ...])**

Produce a directory listing as returned by the LIST command, printing it to standard output. The optional argument is a directory to list (default is the current server directory). Multiple arguments can be used to pass non-standard options to the LIST command. If the last argument is a function, it is used as a callback function as for retrlines(); the default prints to sys.stdout. This method returns None.

Comment: do you know where can I find documentation about passing functions to FTP.dir(), e.g. can I pass a different function to FTP.dir() that returns drwxr-xr-x in one variable and the name Deltas in another?